# Execute code if user is not logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have this code on top of my index.php (login page). I'm trying to redirect logged in users on their respective pages when they access the login page. And I want to execute the login page if the user is not logged in. Here's my code.

```
<?php   
session_start();
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 0){
    header("Location: admin/home.php");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 1){
    header("Location: user/home.php?err=logged-in");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 2){
    header("Location: businesshead/home.php");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 3){
    header("Location: scma/home.php");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 4){
    header("Location: scm/home.php");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 5){
    header("Location: finance/home.php");
}
if($_SESSION['access_level'] == 6){
    header("Location: gm/home.php");
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['access_level'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Thank you so much! :)

EDIT:
My problem is if I put this code on top of my index.php file, an infinite loop happens and causes it not to run.

If the user is not logged in, execute the login page. And if the user is logged in already (and tried to access the logged in page), redirect them to their respective pages.

Comment: What's your question / problem?

Comment: What you are trying to ask ?

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: A `header('Location:...');` does not terminate script execution. You need to add an `exit;` after each `header()`

Comment: I'm not answering your question, but your code will be cleaner if you use a switch statement.

Comment: I've edited the question. I was in a rush when I posted this. My apologies. :)

Answer (score 0):

you forget the exit() after the header

```
<?php    
   header("Location: admin/home.php");   
  exit();      
?>
```

or

```
<?php    
       header("Location: admin/home.php");   
      exit;      
    ?>
```

this link could help you : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code not beauty, We **assume** your login page is `login.php` and any access have default location.

After login:

```
$access_location[0] = 'admin/home.php';
$access_location[1] = 'user/home.php?err=logged-in';
$access_location[2] = 'businesshead/home.php';
$access_location[3] = 'scma/home.php';
$access_location[4] = 'scm/home.php';
$access_location[5] = 'finance/home.php';
$access_location[6] = 'gm/home.php';

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['access_level'])) { //if login in session is not set
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}else{
  header("location:".$access_location[(int) $_SESSION['access_level']]);
  exit();
}
```

and after any redirect you must be `exit()` from code.

Comment: More DRY with single exit call.  Better check, too, that the key exists in the array.